# how to return something else when nothing is found?

Tags: sqlite

My current query:

```
select timestamp from messagesTable
where partner_jid='" + lastUserJid + "' AND msg='.roll'
order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

This works fine... unless the values don't exist in the database.
If values do not exist in database, then it should `Select * messagesTable;` or do nothing if possible.

Is there a way to add a check for that within the same query? It has to be the same query unfortunately because I need to execute things through adb shell. I've been trying things out with CASE but I do not really understand much about SQL.

Comment: And what should happen if the value does not exist?

Comment: If the value does not exist then just Select * from messagesTable; sorry, should have added that @CL.

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: done! I really hope this is possible

Comment: What do you mean with "do nothing"? The query *already* does nothing if no row is found. And a query always returns a fixed number of columns; please decide what columns you want.

Comment: Basically, the result of that query becomes my new integer I need to work with in my code, and if the row is not found, the integer becomes "error: column not found" or something similar, so the code crashes because that's obviously not a valid integer. I guess if it is not found, it can select any other timestamp instead, query for that would be ''Select timestamp from messagesTable order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110046/discussion-between-dysanix-official-and-cl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append a second query, with a WHERE filter that checks whether the first query did not return anything:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT timestamp
      FROM messagesTable
      WHERE partner_jid = ?
        AND msg = '.roll'
      ORDER BY timestamp DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT -1                           -- or "timestamp FROM msgTab", or whatever
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT timestamp
                  FROM messagesTable
                  WHERE partner_jid = ?
                    AND msg = '.roll');
```